# Predict the products of the controlled oxidation of 2-methylpentan-2-ol

Tags: organic-chemistry

> Predict the products of the controlled oxidation of 2-methylpentan-2-ol.

[image: 2-methylpentan-2-ol]

From what I know, since 2-methylpentan-2-ol is a tertiary alcohol, there should be no reaction. However, my textbook states that the product includes 2-methylpentanone.

**Edit:** In response to the comments, my textbook neither specifies the isomer nor mentions any given conditions. I hate Nelson

Comment: What conditions are given for the oxidation?

Comment: Nothing will happen under "controlled" conditions with any of the common oxidizing reagents.  Under forcing conditions elimination of water to form olefins can occur along with epoxide formation and general molecular fragmentation.  BTW, which isomer of 2-methylpentanone does your textbook claim is formed?

Comment: The "**reactant** includes 2-methylpentanone"?  Or the product?   And what molecule is meant by "2-methylpentanone"?  4-methyl-2-pentanone?  Or 3-methyl-2-pentanone?  Or 2-methyl-3-pentanone?  It's hard to see how any of those could be produced in high yield through the oxidation of this alcohol.

Comment: I suppose under dehydrating conditions the preferred product would be 2-methyl-2-pentene?  Could that alkene be oxidized to 2-methyl-3-pentanone?

Comment: Given the level that book is aimed at, this seems far more like a typo than a genuine question. As @Ron pointed out, the most likely thing to happen is elimination.... anything after that is getting into significantly non 12th chemistry

Comment: @CurtF. I meant the product. I changed it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -2):

Tertiary alcohols are resistant to oxidation in neutral or alkaline solution, but are readily oxidized by acidified oxidizing agents.

In your case two products will be acetone and propionic acid.

http://chemistry.tutorcircle.com/organic-chemistry/tertiary-alcohol.html

Comment: This simply isn't true. Even the Jones reagent (18M sulfuric acid and stochiometric chromic anhydride ) doesn't touch tertiary alcohols.  There are indeed methods but *reasily oxidised* is simply nonsense

Comment: @NotNicolaou If you are unfamiliar with the topic study it before commenting/downvoting http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01190a040 You cannot oxidize it using a school chemistry textbook, but you are allowed to oxidize them once you go to a university.

Comment: Look at the limited substrate scope of that paper. This is not a general trivial method. I've also found that textbooks don't make very good oxidants....

Comment: @NotNicolaou Look at the link in my post. Scroll to the very bottom.
 
http://chemistry.tutorcircle.com/organic-chemistry/tertiary-alcohol.html This is the reaction we are talking about.

Comment: Like I said.  Look at the crappy substrate scope. If you'd like to continue this please do so in chat

Comment: @NotNicolaou http://chemistry.tutorcircle.com/organic-chemistry/tertiary-alcohol.html Read this link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42772/discussion-between-sixtytrees-and-notnicolaou).

Comment: ["The carbon atom bonded to oxygen must also bear a hydrogen atom.         Tertiary alcohols (R3C–OH) cannot be oxidized in this fashion."](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/alcohol2.htm)

Comment: ["Tertiary Alcohols: These are resistant to oxidation because they have no hydrogen atoms attached to the oxygen bearing carbon 
(carbinol carbon)."](http://crab.rutgers.edu/~alroche/Ch11.pdf)

Comment: ["Tertiary alcohols are not oxidized by acidified sodium or potassium dichromate(VI) solution - there is no reaction whatsoever"](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Organic_Chemistry/Alcohols/Reactivity_of_Alcohols/The_Oxidation_of_Alcohols#Tertiary_alcohols)

Comment: ["Tertiary alcohols cannot be oxidised (no carbinol C-H)"](http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/351/Carey5th/Ch15/ch15-4-6.html)

Comment: ["What happens when we try to oxidize a tertiary alcohol? The answer is simple: Nothing happens."](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/2organic/aldehyde.html)

Comment: ["Tertiary alcohols cannot be oxidized unless harsh conditions are used that cause complete structural degradation."](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/2/vlu/oxidation_reduktion/oxi_alk.vlu.html)

Comment: ["Tertiary alcohols do not undergo oxidation."](http://www.chem.latech.edu/~deddy/chem252/AlcoholEther.htm)

Comment: @f'' In school they don't. In university they do.

Comment: I see a lot of hostility in this comment section and I would like to ask everyone to [be nice](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) to each other.